# Prevent call of function on object being deleted

Tags: c++, multithreading, smart-pointers, undefined-behavior, dangling-pointer

I'm trying to fix an issue caused by call of method on object that is being destructed which results in my application crash. I have following classes:

```
// Forward declarations
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B(A* aPtr) : m_pA(aPtr) { Schedule(); }
    ~B() { Timer::ref().Cancel(m_TimerId); }

    void Schedule();
    void Update();

private:
    A* m_pA;
    int32_t m_TimerId;
}

void B::Schedule()
{
    m_TimerId = Timer::ref().Schedule(1000, [this]() { Update(); });
}

void B::Update()
{
    m_pA->DoSomething();
}

class A
{
public:
    void Create() { m_B = std::make_unique<B>(); }
    void DoSomething() {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_B;
}
```

Basically class A holds `unique_ptr` to the class B, which stores raw ptr to the A. B uses singleton instance of Timer, which **runs in different thread**, and it schedules function B::Update() to execute on that thread every 1000ms. Sometimes when I destroy object, which stores `A` as a member variable on stack, `A` is destroyed, but theres a dangling pointer to it inside class `B`, which causes function `B::Update()` invoked from another thread, to crash the application, as m_pA* is not `nullptr`, so this causes undefined behavior.

How should I handle this, to prevent my application from crashing? Would explicitly setting `m_pA = nullptr`; in `B::~B()` sufficient?

Comment: So why isn't the thread a member of B; and then ~B can join on the thread to make sure that there's no invalid memory anywhere.

Comment: why should it be? Timer, or more specifically scheduler, is meant to be global (yeah poor design choice, singletons, bla bla...) and has its own thread...

Comment: `blah blah` well, because otherwise you end up in cases where you get a crash because of threads working on objects that have been destroyed because you haven't fully defined the scope of the data

Comment: Agreed... you should re-work your object ownership.  You might be able to resolve this by ensuring the timer doesn't fire on B after it's destroyed... i.e. cancel it at ~B.

Comment: @mark the issue is also the ability to stop B being destroyed during update...

Comment: @mark I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that ~B cancels scheduled event, but this still does not work

Comment: Then `Timer::Schedule` may not be a fire and forget function. Have it return a handle by which the scheduled task may be killed. Then just have `B`'s d'tor do the killing. You didn't specify *how* `B` cancels the event, but it's obvious *that* is buggy.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's exactly what I do. B holds Id of scheduled event as member, and in it's destructor it calls Timer's Cancel method, with Id as param

Comment: Well, that's not what your example shows. Have a read about how one should create a [mcve]. As for your problem, you can't solve it on the client side. Your `Timer` is broken. Fix *that*.

Comment: @StoryTeller Rather than stating obvious, I would be glad if you had proposed solution

Comment: I'd have been happy if you posted a proper MCVE, but we can't all have what we want.

Answer (score 1):

> Would explicitly setting m_pA = nullptr; in B::~B() sufficient?

No.  This is going to cause you headaches later because not only will you still have a race condition (consider the case where the thread reads the value, the pointer is set to null, the object is deleted, the thread then tries to use the object), you will also end up trying to read memory from an object you have just deleted.

> How should I handle this, to prevent my application from crashing?

Make sure that B has a longer life time than the thread (the easiest way to do this is make the thread owned by B) and to ensure that all shared memory is protected when accessed (if read/write).  Remember, you not only have to ensure that update() isn't called on deleted data; but that you don't delete data while update is being called.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible for B to own the thread. Isn't there another solution to this?

Comment: @mezo Make something else own B and the thread so that that object can ensure that the lifetime of the 2 are tied as required

Answer (score 0):

If it's crashing within `B::Update()`, then that tells me that `Timer::ref().Cancel()` will return even before it's fully canceled the timer in the other thread, including if the timer is executing the scheduled function. If you can change how `Timer`'s `Cancel()` works, or add another method to it, I'd make it guarantee the timer is truly canceled/completed for your id. That way destroying `A` will invoke `~B()` which will cancel the timer and either never invoke `Update()` or at least not return until `Update()` is complete if it's in the middle of that.

But assuming you can't do that, then the only thing I can think of is making `B` a `std::shared_ptr` in `A`, and giving the thread a `std::weak_ptr` to that `B`, and trying to get its `shared_ptr` from the `weak_ptr` in the Timer's scheduled function callback. That way `B::Update()` will only be invoked if the `B` object is alive, and it will keep it alive for the duration of `Update()`. Then your next problem is keeping `A` alive, since `Update()` invokes `m_pA->DoSomething();`, and that too can be handled by `B` holding a `weak_ptr` to `A`, and making `A` a shared pointer object. BUT, the problem with any of that is that you're starting the timer on `B`'s construction, and before C++17 you can't get a `std::weak_ptr` from a shared object during its construction. So you have to move `Schedule()` to be invoked by `A`.

So something like this:

```
class A;

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
public:
    B() = default;
    ~B() { Timer::ref().Cancel(m_TimerId); }

    void Schedule(const std::shared_ptr<A>& aPtr);
    void Update();

private:
    std::weak_ptr<B> weak_from_this()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }

private:
    std::weak_ptr<A> wkA;
    int32_t m_TimerId{0};
};

void B::Schedule(const std::shared_ptr<A>& aPtr)
{
    wkA = aPtr;
    m_TimerId = Timer::ref().Schedule(1000,
                    [myself = weak_from_this()]()
                    {
                        if (auto me = myself.lock())
                        {
                            me->Update();
                        }
                    });
}

void B::Update()
{
    if (auto pA = wkA.lock())
    {
        pA->DoSomething();
    }
}

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    void Create()
    {
        m_B = std::make_shared<B>();
        m_B->Schedule(shared_from_this());
    }

    void DoSomething() {}

private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> m_B;
};
```

Note that the above did some things that are only necessary until C++17. Also, this means that users of your `A` class now have to create it as a shared object, which might be undesirable.